# Order by created_date if less than 1 month old, else sort by updated_date

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1da00/5

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
products
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   name    | price | created_date | updated_date |
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
| chair     |    50 | 10/12/2016   | 1/4/2017     |
| desk      |   100 | 11/4/2016    | 12/27/2016   |
| TV        |   500 | 12/1/2016    | 1/2/2017     |
| computer  |  1000 | 12/28/2016   | 1/1/2017     |
| microwave |   100 | 1/3/2017     | 1/4/2017     |
| toaster   |    20 | 1/9/2017     | 1/9/2017     |
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

I want to order this table in a way where if the product was created less than 30 days those results should show first (and be ordered by the updated date). If the product was created 30 or more days ago I want it to show after (and have it ordered by updated date within that group)

This is what the result should look like:

```
products - desired results
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
|   name    | price | created_date | updated_date |
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
| toaster   |    20 | 1/9/2017     | 1/9/2017     |
| microwave |   100 | 1/3/2017     | 1/4/2017     |
| computer  |  1000 | 12/28/2016   | 1/1/2017     |
| chair     |    50 | 10/12/2016   | 1/4/2017     |
| TV        |   500 | 12/1/2016    | 1/2/2017     |
| desk      |   100 | 11/4/2016    | 12/27/2016   |
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

I've started writing this query:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN created_date > NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS order_index
FROM products
ORDER BY order_index, created_date DESC
```

but that only bring the rows with `created_date` less thatn 30 days to the top, and then ordered by `created_date`. I want to also sort the rows where `order_index` = 1 by `updated_date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in version 9.3 only positional column numbers or expressions involving table columns can be used in `order by` so `order_index` is not available to `case` at all and its position is not *well defined* because it comes after `*` in the column list.

This will work.

```
order by  
  created_date <= ( current_date - 30 ) , case
     when created_date > ( current_date - 30 ) then  created_date
     else updated_date end desc
```

Alternatively a common table expression can be used to wrap the result and then that can be ordered by any column.

```
WITH q AS(
    SELECT *,
        CASE 
            WHEN created_date > NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS order_index
    FROM products
)
SELECT * FROM q
ORDER BY 
    order_index , 
    CASE order_index 
      WHEN 0 THEN created_date 
      WHEN 1 THEN updated_date
    END DESC;
```

A third approach is to exploit nulls.

```
order by
  case 
    when created_date > ( current_date - 30 ) then created_date 
  end desc nulls last,
  updated_date desc;
```

This approach can be useful when the ordering columns are of different types.

Comment: This doesn't give the correct results. Also, can you utilize `order_index`. I plan to add more values to `order_index` so it shouldn't be taken out.

Comment: oops. order_index. is harder to use, computed columns can only be referenced by position, so they cant be used in expressions.